# Nesting shortcodes results in the inner shortcode being placed AFTER outer shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I'm trying to use nested shortcodes, but i'm having problems with it.

Everytime i try to nest two shortcodes created by me...

First declared in functions.php (the inner):

```
function p_generic_shortcode( $atts , $content = null )
{
    return '<p class="pov generic">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</p>';
}
add_shortcode( 'pov-generic', 'p_generic_shortcode' );
```

Second declared in functions.php (the outer):

```
function f_girl_shortcode( $atts , $content = null )
{
    return '<p class="talk girl">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</p>';
}
add_shortcode( 'talk-girl', 'f_girl_shortcode' );
```

When i enter the following code in bbpress editor:

```
[talk-girl]TEXT[pov-generic]OTHER TEXT[/pov-generic][/talk-girl]
```

It outputs the follow code:

```
<p class="talk girl">TEXT</p>
<p class="pov generic">OTHER TEXT</p>
```

And not as i expected:

```
<p class="talk girl">TEXT<p class="pov generic">OTHER TEXT</p></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2832179/1743124) for the best result of shortcode, especially when you are outputting some HTML in it:

```
function f_girl_shortcode( $atts , $content = null )
{
    ob_start(); ?>
          <div class="talk girl"><?php echo do_shortcode($content); ?></div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'talk-girl', 'f_girl_shortcode' );
```

and

```
function p_generic_shortcode( $atts , $content = null )
{
    ob_start(); ?>
          <div class="pov generic"><?php echo do_shortcode($content); ?></div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'pov-generic', 'p_generic_shortcode' );
```

### EDIT

Yes, block level element is not the issue, I found the issue is the `<p>` tag only. The `<p>` tag doesn't support another `<p>` tag or any block level element within ([More here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4291467/1743124)). So I changed my answer with `<div>` tags.

And another good practice, I tend to follow: the `[talk-girl]` is the parent, and the `[pov-generic]` is the child. In such case, I follow a simple rule: no child without a parent - so *declare parent first, then the child* - it may be nothing, but in some cases, it's many thing. I changed the position of the declaration of the code too. :)

#### Reference:

- [Output Control Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) - PHP.net
- [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) - WordPress Codex

Comment: Still won't work.
This output me

    `<p class="talk girl">TEXT</p>`
    `<p class="pov generic">OTHER TEXT</p>`
Something that i realized: if i change the HTML tag for one of the shortcodes, it will print accordingly. But if the two shortcodes output a block element (div or p) it close the parent and the child is output after it.

Comment: @Vico you are right. Edited my answer now with the cause.

Comment: SOLVED! I just put the pov-generic shortcode (the only can go as a child in my system) in a span element. Worked flawlessly an even wordpress enclose the non-child shortcode with a p.

Thank you so much for the answer!!